Prove that $Q(x)=Q(x-1)$ must be constant
This one is subproblem from "Find all polynomial P(x) which satisfies equation $xp(x-1)=(x-3)p(x)$
By trying $x=0,1,2$ you get that $P(x)=x*(x-1)(x-2)*Q(x)$
By inserting new equation into previous one we get that $Q(x)=Q(x-1)$.
I tried assuming opposite that they are polynomials and I got this equation:
$a_n(x-1)^{n-1} + a_{n-1}(x-1)^{n-1}+...+ a_1(x-1) +a_0=a_nx^{n-1} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+ a_1x +a_0$
I don't know how to prove that this is contradiction.

Cf. this question

In general, if a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $Q(x)=Q(x-1)$ for all $x$, then $Q(x)-Q(0)$ will have infinitely many roots.
But a nonzero polynomial over a field cannot have roots more than its degree, due to the Euclidean algorithm.

What if polynomial is infinitive and has infinitive number of roots?

@StephanieV:  there is no such thing as an “infinitive polynomial”

@StephanieV Polynomials, by definition, only have finitely many terms. If you allow infinite sums you need to deal with convergence. When this is done you can have infinitely many roots, for example, $\sin$ has a taylor series which converges for every real and is $2\pi$-periodic, so every value is taken infinitely many times.

If $Q(x) = Q(x-1)$ for all $x$, then the polynomial $A(x) = Q(x) - Q(a)$ for some fixed $a\in\mathbb R$ will have infinitely many roots ($x=a-n$, with $n\in\mathbb N$ is always a root). However, the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$.
This implies $A(x) = 0$ and therefore $Q(x) = Q(a)$ for all $a$ (that is, $Q(x)$ is constant).
